# UILongPressGestureRecognizer not working on first cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have tried to add a UILongPressGestureRecognizer to show an alert view when a cell is held down however it doesn't work on the first cell in the table view for some reason. so it works on all the other cells however the cell at index path.row 0 doesn't work. anyone know how to fix this?

my code:

UIGestureRecognizerDelegate added to .h
 UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress; implemented at the top;

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *identifier = @"activeComputers";
    ActiveComputersCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[ActiveComputersCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    }

    //gesture recognizer
    longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(detectCellHold)];
    longPress.delegate = self;
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:longPress];

    cell.lblComputer.text = [computer objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.lblCustomer.text = [customer objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (void)detectCellHold{
    CGPoint p = [longPress locationInView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexOfHold = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:p];
    if (longPress.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        NSLog(@"UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded");
        //Do Whatever You want on End of Gesture
    }
    else if (longPress.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
        NSLog(@"%ld", (long)indexOfHold.row);
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Computer" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Completed", @"Invoice", nil];
            [alert setTag:1];
            [alert show];

    }
}
```

Update:
It works when i use:

```
- (void)detectCellHold{
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Computer" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Completed", @"Invoice", nil];
                [alert setTag:1];
                [alert show];
            }
```

however this shows the alert multiple times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up on @mityaika07's answer,

Why is that you add the gesture recognizer when you create a cell ?

You might as well add it to the `ActiveComputersCell` class

```
   UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(detectCellHold)];
   longPress.delegate = self;
   [self addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
```

This way you automatically get the specific cell instance for every long press.

Comment: @JordanNewton My suggestion was to move the initializing and adding of a gesture recognizer to the UITableViewCell class, in your case ActiveComputersCell, you are trying to determine the indexPath of the clicked cell which would not be necessary if you implement the gesture callback method on the same class too. Please let me know once you try this.

Comment: I've done that and it appears to have worked. how would i go about stopping it from showing the alert twice?

Comment: @JordanNewton Great, i would make sure the gesture is added only once and the gesture callback method is only implemented once in the ActiveComputersCell class.

Answer (score 0):

It bad way to add recognizer, during scrolling, you add new recognizers to cell, which already have recognizer, do this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *identifier = @"activeComputers";
    ActiveComputersCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[ActiveComputersCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];

        //gesture recognizer
        longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(detectCellHold)];
        longPress.delegate = self;
        [cell addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
    }   

    cell.lblComputer.text = [computer objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.lblCustomer.text = [customer objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply however this has stopped it working at all ?